# How to show that this set is an algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

I am self studying Algebraic geometry from the notes of a senior. I am struck on this assignment question, so I thought of asking help on this website.

> Show that this set is an algebraic set $\{(\cos t,\sin t)\in A_{\mathbb{R}}^2 :t\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

I think this is not an algebraic set. If this is an algebraic set and call this set X, X=V(S) for some finite set S of some polynomials {$f_1,..., f_n$}. (If I am not wrong, S should always have finite number of polynomials.) Now this set X can't be a finite union of Algebraic sets( and if it is infinite union of algebraic sets then it can't be algebraic anymore) as  solutions of finite number of polynomials can't cover [-1,1].

> Kindly tell me what mistake is in my solution as I have proved the opposite of what was asked in the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by lulu, if we put $S=\{x^2+y^2-1\} \subset \mathbb{R}[x,y]$, then $V(S)=X$, where $X$ is the set in the question. I will just point out one more thing. Usually the definitions are made as follows:

Let $K$ be a field. If $S \subseteq K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$, then $V(S)$ denotes the collection of all $p \in A^n_K$ such that $f(p)=0$ for every $f \in S$. A subset $X \subseteq A^n_k$ is said to be (affine) algebraic if $X=V(S)$ for some $S \subseteq K[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$. It is usually NOT required that $S$ is a finite set, especially when $K$ is not finite.